# Generate Excel Spreadsheet with a Freezepane

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I've trying to create a spreadsheet with a freeze pane for the first 5 row. I've got it creating an excel spreadsheet but for some reason my freeze pane only freezes the first 2 rows and first 2 columns.

```
With objExcelAssist.worksheet
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Set xlApp = objExcelAssist.Application
    xlApp.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End With
```

I've tried doing:

```
Dim rv As Object
Dim rng As Object

Set rng = rv.Range(rv.Cells(4, 2), rv.Cells(4, 2))
rng.select
rv.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

But I get the error: 'Object variable or With block variable not set'

Any help on how I can get my Excel document to freeze the first top 5 rows would be great.

Thanks

---- Edit ----

```
With objExcelAssist.worksheet
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

    .Rows(1).RowHeight = 21
    .columns(1).ColumnWidth = 11
    .Rows(objExcelReport.firstDataRow - 1).Autofilter
End With
```

I got this now with 'Range'

[image: Tries a suggestion someone posted but still got the same problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `.` in front of `Range` should fix it.

My guess is that your function is in an Access VBA module and not in an Excel one, and VBA doesn't have a default object for the range property.

Since you are in a `With <a WorkSheet object>` block, any property without the reference object, that is any `.<property name>` refers to that WorkSheet.

Comment: Well progress has been made, I now get ActiveWindow is a variable not defined? Do I need to find ActiveWindow as a variable?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working with the information you gave me :)

Comment: My guess is that you tested a macro in Excel and now you want to perform the same actions from a macro in Access, and you don't have access to all the default global objects of Excel. I always try not to use any default object. I always put a WorkSheet object before Range or Cell or Sort, and before all the Sort key ranges. So the code is more portable.

Answer (score 1):

It's much more simple then that!
Select the first cell in the row you want to freeze. For 5 rows:

```
Sub Makro1()
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I get a Compile error:
Sub or Function not defined : 

I get this error on 'Range'

Comment: See updates answer. Also read more on subs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dz1z94ha.aspx

Comment: Even in a sub-routine, it still says Compile Error, SUb or Function not defined, error is still on 'Range'